# "the" VS "plurals"

Tags: definite-article

1. After investigating the background of the media organization,the reporter, and the subject of the interview, BPA decides whether to accept or reject the invitation.
2. After investigating the background of media organizations, reporters, and the subjects of interviews, BPA decides whether to accept or reject the invitation.

"media organization" could be any news outlets, and reporter can be Mike, Lucy and any one. Which one is correct, 1) or 2)?

Comment: This is a matter of context, not grammar. How many media organizations,  reporters and interview subjects *are* there? The first sentence is correct if there is only one of each, and the second is correct if there is more than one of each. (It's likely you'll also want plural *backgrounds* and *invitations* in the second sentence.)

Comment: We do not know how many, it could be a media organization or many organization coming at a time. In the case where there may be more than one outlet approaching the company, would be the first one correct? Many thinks.

Comment: @YongxueLaw Could you tell us the surrounding sentences? Especially a couple before the sentence at issue.

Comment: @userr2684291 it is in a policy on external communications as a rule.

Comment: I figured as much. What you provided isn't enough to answer this question, so suit yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context: BPA always does its research prior to accepting media invitations.

Possibility 1): Yesterday, BPA received **an invitation** from Sky News. After investigating **the** background of **the media organization**,**the** reporter, and **the subject** of the interview, BPA will decide whether to accept or reject the invitation.

The use of "the" means there is only one of each, and that they are specific to a discussion or context that is already known, earlier in the text or content.

Possibility 2) As **a general rule**: After investigating the background of **a media organization, reporter, and the subject of an interview**, BPA decides whether to accept or reject an invitation.

The lack of "the" would only make sense **in a general statement.**

Possiblity 3) As a general rule, after investigating the background of media organization**s**, reporter**s**, and subject**s** of interviews, BPA decides whether to accept or reject invitation**s**.

General statements can also be in the plural.

Comment: Could "the" be used to make a generation statement. So the outlet could be CNN, WSJ, and reporter could be anyone from CNN?

Comment: @Yongxue Law Please write it out.

Comment: @Yongxue Law:  No, that would be too specific. When *the* is being used in a generalization the meaning is *whatever*, here, whatever reporter it happens to be on the given occasion.

Comment: If you say: Yesterday, the BPA received **the** invitation from CNN. [that means you already know which invitation is under discussion or that you expected that particular one.] The rest would remain like 1) and will decide.

Answer (score 0):

A statement about BPA's standard operating procedure is a form of generalization.

A generalization can be made using the indefinite article, the definite article, or the plural.

> A cat has claws.
>
> The cat has claws.
>
> Cats have claws.

Each resolves to a generality:

**a**:  any  cat.

**the**:  the prototypical cat.

**cats**: all cats

P.S. The use of the simple present **decides** in the original sentences leaves us only one interpretation: they are general statements about standard practice.  (In a "narrative" the simple present can be used to tell a story about a particular instance rather than a generality:  *He takes the teapot from the shelf and sets it on the table.*  But the original sentences are not from such a story.)

Comment: Yes, and my possiblity 1) shows how one goes from **a** to **the** in the **same paragraph**. That's what is difficulty for ELLers. The point is showing how one moves from one to the other or not. And how there are differences.

Comment: @Lambie: Your #1 is not an option with the *original* sentences, which use the simple present verb **decides**, indicating generalization.

Comment: Context is everything. I adapted the sentences (will decide) to broaden what would be correct. It's seems picky on your part to criticize that rather than work with the OP's actual material.

Comment: @Lambie: I *was* working the OP's actual material. You weren't. You've got it backwards.  And I'm not "criticizing" but responding to your comment attached my answer above. You don't need to "school" me on what is difficult for ELLers.

Comment: I stand by my first comment.

Comment: Yep, it is general statements about standard practice. You mean both 1) and 2) of my suggested sentence are okay, and "the" can be used to refer to general stuff.?

Comment: @YongxueLaw: As the answer says, *A generalization can be made using the indefinite article, the definite article, or the plural.*